# Why I am not able to get the specific column in psql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in my psql db called *cls* and user called *cls*
then tries to get the specific column from the existing table [name: test] but I am not able to retrieve the table.

Snippets as below:

```
psql -U cls
    
cls # select * from test;
      name |          ip  |      user   |       password   |      group |             created_on         
-----------+--------+------+--------------+--------+----------------------------
     server | 1.1.1.1   | test | pwd         | gp1   | 2022-08-04 13:55:00.765548
```

```
cls # select ip from test where name='server';
LINE 1: select ip from test where name='server';
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "test. ip".

cls # select test.ip from test where name='server';
LINE 1: select ip from test where name='server';
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "test. ip".

cls # select t.ip from test t;
LINE 1: select t.ip from test t;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "t. ip".
```

I tried double quotes and single quotes but no luck.

Comment: Do you have the DDL you used to create this table?  Did you write it in Word or something?  There is a line separator character in each of your column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, your column isn't called `ip`, it's called  `ip` - notice the "funny" character before the i.

Comment: thank you i understand now. when i copied from one test file to other looks like there is special char got added